How to assign multiple Azure policies exemptions with Terraform
I have assigned an initiative with terraform and now would like to add examptions by their ID. How to do?
data "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "iso27001" {
 display_name = "ISO 27001:2013"
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group_policy_assignment" "iso27001_assignment" {
  name                 = "iso27001_assignment"
  resource_group_id    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  policy_definition_id = data.azurerm_policy_set_definition.iso27001.id
  description          = "Assignment of the ISO 27001:2013 initiative to subscription."
  display_name         = "ISO 27001:2013 Governance"
  location             = "Switzerland North"
  identity { 
    type = "SystemAssigned" 
  }
}

Desired exemption (the first, I need to do this 5 times):
Description
Audit provisioning of an Azure Active Directory administrator for your SQL server to enable Azure AD authentication. Azure AD authentication enables simplified permission management and centralized identity management of database users and other Microsoft services
Effect
AuditIfNotExists
Type
Built-in
Mode
Indexed
Category
SQL
Definition location
--
Definition ID
/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/1f314764-cb73-4fc9-b863-8eca98ac36e9


To add exemptions for a specific policy initiative in Terraform, you can use the azurerm_resource_group_policy_exemption resource, Follow the Terraform registry for more details.

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.

To add exemptions for a specific policy initiative in Terraform, you can use the azurerm_resource_group_policy_exemption resource.
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "fjgjgjgjgja-a507-d7e60e5f09a9"
}

data "azurerm_policy_set_definition" "example" {
  display_name = "ISO 27001:2013"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "webapp-RG"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group_policy_assignment" "example" {
  name                 = "iso27001_assignment"
  resource_group_id    = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  policy_definition_id = data.azurerm_policy_set_definition.example.id
  description          = "Assignment of the ISO 27001:2013 initiative to the resource group."
  display_name         = "ISO 27001:2013 Governance"
  location             = "Switzerland North"
  identity { 
    type = "SystemAssigned" 
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group_policy_exemption" "example" {
  name                 = "ISO27001Governance"
  resource_group_id    = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  policy_assignment_id = azurerm_resource_group_policy_assignment.example.id
  exemption_category   = "Waiver"
  expires_on           = "2025-12-31T23:59:59Z"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group_policy_assignment.example ]
}

Terraform apply

After executing the code, the policy exception has been created in azure policy assignment.

Reference:   azurerm_resource_group_policy_exemption

Isn't that an exception to the whole initiative? I still want the initiative with all these policies. Just five less.

Yes, Its for whole initiative. Do you want to assign an exception only or include policy assignment?

Yeah. I want to assign an exception only for included policy assignments but still keep the initiative.

How many initiatives do you want to assign an exception to?

Probably five policy assignments out of the ISO27001 Initiative

Exception will apply to the whole Initiative.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have provided foreach method code in discussion chat for multiple assignment and exception. Kindly check and let us know if you still need any help.
